# How does scrapyd determine the 'latest' version of a project?

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

According to the documentations, when deploying a project to scrapyd, I can use the git commit hash as the version, by doing this:

```
$ scrapyd-deploy default -p myproject --version GIT
```

The documentation also says that scrapyd can keep multiple versions of the same project, but will only run spiders from the latest version.

In that case, how does scrapyd determine which version is the 'latest' to use?

I hope it doesn't sort the git commit hashes lexicographically and use that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in their [docs](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html):

> Scrapyd will use the greatest version when not specified, the version must be comparable according to [distutils.version.LooseVersion](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/distutils.version.LooseVersion-class.html).

This means that using GIT as version doesn't make much sense, which is a rather big issue

Comment: By default, `scrapyd-client deploy` uses the epoch timestamp for the version number.